# How to determine convergence of $\int _0^1 \frac{3cosx}{x^2+x^\frac{1}{2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I'm stuck on how to determine if the improper integral
$$\int _0^1 \frac{3\cos x}{x^2+x^\frac{1}{2}}dx$$
converges.

The only tool I have (I think) is to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and try to find the antiderivative, but I'm convinced its not feasible to find the antiderivative

Any pointers or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have to evaluate it (what you said in the body), or just determine whether it converges (what your title says)? Although you are right the antiderivative is probably too hard to find, if you just have to determine convergence you may not need the antiderivative.

Comment: Sorry, I just needed to determine whether it converges. Rafael pointed me in the right direction. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=3\cos(x)(x^2+x^{1/2})^{-1}$. Since $f$ is continuos at $x=1$, we have a unique problem in $x=0$. We can use de comparation criteria by taking limit. Since
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{1/\sqrt{x}} = 1
$$
and 
$$
\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx = 2< \infty
$$
We have the result. The improper integral is convergent.

Comment: are you able to elaborate on what "de comparation criteria"? I'm not really sure what the step was

Comment: Never mind, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I didnt realize the comparison test was valid on the interval (0,1]